# ZnO layer as a passivity layer

Tags: electrochemistry, metal, conductivity

I have bought a zinc sheet and with SEM I can see a ZnO layer, which is a passivity layer. But when I connect this sheet to a conductive wire, le zn sheet is conductive too. Is that normal ?  the ZnO layer should prevent the Zn/wire connection from, isn't it ?

Comment: Depends how thick the ZnO is, how the wire is attached, and how closely you look at the behavior of the junction.

Comment: Bear in mind that ZnO is a semiconductor. It is a wide band gap semiconductor. Nevertheless, it is a poor choice as an insulating layer. More so if it the layer is thin.